# Use memoir's \AtBeginClass to disable multicols on chapter title?

Tags: memoir

I've seen other solutions for turning off multicols in order to make a chapter title span columns, but they all seem to require a custom hack instead of a simple package-option solution.

Somewhere in my research, I saw mention of memoir's "\AtBeginClass" and "\AtEndClass", and I got the idea of using those to do the job.  I think I've misunderstood something, though, because I have been utterly unable to get it to work.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}

% these work as expected
    \AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
    \AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

% these don't seem to be working
    \AtBeginClass{chapter}{\end{multicols}}
    \AtEndClass{chapter}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
    \AtBeginClass{section}{\end{multicols}}
    \AtEndClass{section}{\begin{multicols}{2}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{My Chapter}
    \lipsum
    \section{My Section}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively, I would accept a similar method of turning off/on the standard "\twocolumn" before/after each chapter or section title.

Comment: I wonder if I've mistaken "class" for something more general.  Is the term "class" used to refer specifically to that decided by "\documentclass"?

Comment: Chapter and sections are not classes, so your code does nothing (never executes). Perhaps you should explain a bit better what your goal is.

Comment: D'oh!  Boy, do I feel silly.  Anyway, my goal is to have both the chapter title and the section title span two columns.  The normal "\twocolumn" does that just fine for the chapter, but I've seen no way to do the same with sections -- at least none that I can yet comprehend.  (I would also like the column-spanning section title to not force a page break.)